# Issue scraping multiple URLs - NFL betting data

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have 2 pieces of code:
1st: Extracts current NFL games on a betting website
2nd: Extracts all the bets on the game URL

First issue is that I can't figure out how to build them into 1 code. Right now I export result to Excel and use VBA to add the start of the URL and the correct '' and commas. I played around with map and join but couldn't make it work.

Bigges issue, however, is that the multiple URL scrape I have set up is buggy - as I only get data from 1st scrape.

URL grabs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

links = [a['href'] for a in soup.find_all('a',{'data-competition': "NFL Preseason Matches"},href=True)]



print(list(set(links)))
#df.to_csv('file.csv')

#str_concat = ',https://www.betfair.com'.join(list(links))

#print(list(set(links)))
#def myfunc(a, b):
#           return a + b

#x = map(myfunc, ('https://www.betfair.com','https://www.betfair.com'), (links))
```

The multiple URL Scrape:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
urls = ['https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football/nfl-preseason-matches/minnesota-vikings-buffalo-bills/29427759',
        'https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football/nfl-preseason-matches/los-angeles-rams-houston-texans/29427770',
        'https://www.betfair.com/sport/american-football/nfl-preseason-matches/pittsburgh-steelers-carolina-panthers/29427758']

for url in urls:
    result2 = requests.get(url)
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')

data = []
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'minimarketview-content'}):
    temp_data = [ alpha for alpha in item.text.split('\n') if alpha != '' ] 
    data.append(temp_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

I expect results from all 3 URL's in one file, but only results from last is shown:

,

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
0,Pittsburgh Steelers,1.42,Carolina Panthers,2.6,,,,,
1,Pittsburgh Steelers,1.75,"-3,5",Carolina Panthers,1.95,"+3,5",,,
2,NuvÃ¦rende antal points:,Over,1.8,"+33,5",Under,1.9,"+33,5",,
3,Pittsburgh Steelers,1.83,-4,Uafgjort,20.0,+4,Carolina Panthers,1.9,+4
4,Pittsburgh Steelers (-4.5) & Over (33.5) points,3.4,Pittsburgh Steelers (-4.5) og under (33.5) point,3.75,Carolina Panthers (+4.5) & Over (33.5) points,3.5,Carolina Panthers (+4.5) og under (33.5) point,3.5,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only the last page **scraped** because you are overwriting `soup` without processing first and send it to data.

Something like this might work better, with a function that process the data from the `for` loop.

Still this code could be better written.

```
def process_data(soup: BeautifulSoup):
    for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'minimarketview-content'}):
        temp_data = [alpha for alpha in item.text.split('\n') if alpha != '']
        data.append(temp_data)


for url in urls:
    result2 = requests.get(url)
    src2 = result2.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src2, 'lxml')
    process_data(soup)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

UPDATE:

To get dynamically the links you are looking for, you have to first request for `https://www.betfair.com/`, there you look for

> `<div class="nav open" data-nav="All Sports" style="display: block;"/>`

This `div` holds a list of allt he categories for the sports offered. Looping on that list you look for

> `<span>American Football</span>`

And then you get the next link, and then repeat the process looking for the block you are interested in, until you get to the end of the chain.

To analyze what blocks are you interested in, use "Inspect" from your web browser, by right clicking on the block you are interested, it will open Dev Tools and you will know exactly what block are you trying to analyze.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It works! Any pointers to how I could implement getting the URL's dynamically into code from first code? Or what functionality to use.

Comment: You should make a different question for that one. You shouldn't be making dual questions posts. If this solved your second issue maybe you might consider marking it solved. For your first issue, better make another question, I'll update my answer with a hint.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that :).

Comment: @mvp1988 No need to be sorry, is not a warning, is just that SO sometimes look harsh, take it as a friendly advice ;-)